# Error compiling mips32

Tags: c++, gcc, mips32

I'm trying to compile MIPS32 code in a virtual machine. The rest of the program is done in C code.
Here the problematic code:

```
"# include "ordenamiento.h"

"# a0 is the pointer to char **, a1 is the start (int), a2 is the end (int)
.overall stoogeSort

.Set noreorder

.cpload $t9

.September reorder

.cprestore

.ent stoogeSort

"#arming the stack
stoogeSort: 
addiu $ sp, -32 

sw $ fp, 28 ($ sp) 
$ sw gp, 24 ($ sp) 
move $ fp, $ sp 
sw $ a0, 32 ($ sp)
sw $ a1, 36 ($ sp) 
sw $ a2, 40 ($ sp) 
b CMP 
FinComp: bgt $ t0, $ zero, noswap 
Swap: addu $ t2, $ a0, $ a1 
----
----
----
. stoogeSort end
```

The problem is that when compiling as follows gcc-c-O0 stoogeSort.S gives me the following errors:

```
stooge.s: 1: Warning: line numbers must be positive, line number 0 rejected
stooge.s: 9: Error: illegal operands `sw $ a0, 32 ($ sp) '
stooge.s: 10: Error: illegal operands `sw $ a1, 36 ($ sp) '
stooge.s: 11: Error: illegal operands `sw $ a2, 40 ($ sp) '
stooge.s: 12: Error: unrecognized opcode `ba CMP '
stooge.s: 13: Error: illegal operands `bgt $ t0, $ zero, noswap '
stooge.s: 14: Error: illegal operands `addu $ t2, $ a0, $ a1 '
stooge.s: 15: Error: illegal operands `addu $ t3, $ a0, $ a2 '
```

What am I doing wrong? Why do I get these errors?

Comment: Do you have an assembler installed that can compile MIPS assembly, and if you do, are you using it instead of the system one?

Comment: The problem was missing the "# include <mips/regdef.h>"
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have got an answer to your question, its better to post it here so that its going to be helpful for those who come here with the same problem.

I am posting the answer here for you.

**The problem was the missing `"# include <mips/regdef.h>"`**